# Woocommerce - how to sort multiple size attributes for product page

Tags: wordpress, sorting, woocommerce

I have more than 500 of size attributes terms.it is hard to drag and drop each to sort it for product details page in woocommerce.

Size Attributes on a product page are showing like this:-

```
SIZE 5
SIZE WOMEN 10 WIDE
SIZE MEN 6.5
SIZE MEN 7
SIZE WOMEN 6.5
SIZE WOMEN 8
SIZE 6
SIZE MEN 7 WIDE
SIZE 10
SIZE WOMEN 10
SIZE WOMEN 6.5 WIDE
```

But want this attrbutes list should be like this:-

```
SIZE 5
SIZE 6
SIZE 10
SIZE MEN 6.5
SIZE MEN 7
SIZE MEN 7 WIDE
SIZE WOMEN 6.5
SIZE WOMEN 6.5 WIDE
SIZE WOMEN 8
SIZE WOMEN 10
SIZE WOMEN 10 WIDE
```

I tried by custom sorting in woocommerce but wan't achieve the result.

Also I am trying to change attributes slug like :-

```
S5
S6.5
SM5
SM5W
SW4
SW4W etc to sort it as mentioned above result.
```

Here sharing product image.

[image]

Comment: is this grouped product?

Comment: No variation product only.

Comment: I'm not able to replicate your screenshot with just WooCommerce using product variations.. What I have is a dropdown. So I can't provide a solution.

Answer (score 0):

From what it looks like, you're wanting to order the attributes alphabetically.

A similar question has been answered here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/308725/woocomerce-order-products-by-float-attribute-in-archive-pages

(Credit goes to @[Krzysiek Dróżdż♦](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/34172/krzysiek-dr%c3%b3%c5%bcd%c5%bc)